# Mass publication of Netlogo applets in hierarchic dir structure

Tags: applet, netlogo

Through a wrapper php script I published some 100-150 authentic Netlogo files on the net.  This works fine: a list of Netlogo files is displayed, you click on the corresponding URL and then HTML is generated for that specific Netlogo file.  There is a problem though.  My Netlogo collection is hierarchical and the Netlogo manual says that if a Netlogo applet uses extensions, the extensions dir should be put right next to the Netlogo source, in the same directory.  Am I forced to organise my collection in a flat directory or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use symbolic links.  Have a single extensions directory in a central location, and then put symbolic links to it wherever you want.